# Is there a name for the number system that's like $\mathbb{Q}$ but without the cancellation law $ax/bx = a/b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, dirichlet-series

Suppose we want to find $42/12$ as a quotient followed by a remainder. One approach is to write $42/12$ as a mixed number via the usual method:
$$\frac{42}{12} = \frac{36+6}{12} = \frac{36}{12}+\frac{6}{12} = 3 + \frac{6}{12}$$
So the answer is $3$ with remainder $6$. However, there's something a bit dissatisfying about this. Note that to write the RHS as a normal-form mixed number, we should simplify our fraction, obtaining $$3+ \frac{1}{2}.$$ Arguably this is slightly disconcerting: to get the correct final answer of remainder $6$ and avoid the incorrect final answer of remainder $1$, we have to *avoid* simplifying. That's perhaps a bit strange. More fundamentally, my issue here is that we can't actually extract the remainder from the rational number we started with. In particular, if someone tells you that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is the rational number $42/12$ and asks you to find the remainder, there's no sensible answer to their question - the remainder could be $1$, or any non-zero multiple of $1$.

For this reason, I'm interested in the number system that's like $\mathbb{Q},$ but without the cancellation law $ax/bx = a/b$. Lets call it $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$. The idea behind $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$ is that it's a quotient of the set of all formal $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of elements of the form $$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots$$ So an example element would be $$\frac{5}{3} + \frac{17}{5},$$ by which we really mean the linear combination $$5\frac{1}{3} + 17\frac{1}{5}.$$ I'm pretty sure the above set can be identified with the [Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Formal_Dirichlet_series) with finitely many terms. We then take a quotient of this ring by assuming that if $a$ and $b$ are integers satisfying $a \mid b$, then letting $c$ denote the integer $b/a$, we have $\frac{b}{a} = c\frac{1}{1}.$ I'm not sure how to translate this into Dirichlet language. Anyhoo, in the resulting set $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$ we've just constructed, which should be a commutative ring if I'm not mistaken, we have $$\frac{42}{12} = 3 + \frac{6}{12} \neq 3 + \frac{1}{2},$$ and so we can extract the remainder of $6$ from the quotient $42/12$, as desired.

I'd be curious to learn more, so:

> **Question.** Does this number system have a name and/or where can I learn more about it?

Comment: You have the ring (integral domain) $D$ of Dirichlet series with finitely many terms and integer coefficients and the evaluation map at $s=1$: $\phi(F(s))=  F(1)$. What do you expect more ? $D$ is not finitely generated over $\Bbb{Z}$ and the ideal $\ker(\phi)= (p_1^{1-s}-1,p_2^{1-s}-1,\ldots)$ is not finitely generated. $\phi(D)=\Bbb{Q}$ means $D/\ker(\phi) \cong \Bbb{Q}$. As ring $D \cong \Bbb{Z}[X_1,X_2,\ldots]$ the isomorphism being $n^{-s}=\prod_j p_j^{-s e_j} \mapsto \prod_j X_j^{e_j}$.

Comment: So are you looking at $\Bbb Z[e_2,e_3,\ldots]$ with the relations $ne_n=1$ and $e_me_m=e_{mn}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I think that's right. That's a good way of explaining it.

Comment: @reuns, well, I'd like to know what other uses or applications it has, and in particular, can we learn interesting things about the modulo and floored integer division operations using this ring?

Comment: @reuns, in particular, I'm interested in the maps $c_n : \tilde{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined as follows: given $x \in \tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$, put $x$ into normal form by ensuring that for each $m > 1$, the coefficient of each $1/m$ is in the set $\{0,\ldots,m-1\}$, and then extracting the coefficient of $1/n$ in this normal form expression. That gives us a family of interesting-looking maps $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, one for each $m$. These aren't morphisms, but I'd love to know if the algebra of $\tilde{\mathbb{Q}}$ interacts with these maps in interesting ways.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, just to be sure, the rational numbers can be constructed by quotienting $\mathbb{Z}[e_2,e_3,e_4,\cdots]$ by the relations $n e_{nm} = e_m$ and $e_n e_m = e_{nm}$, right?